# set a default value on jquery datatable filter column and do an initial filtering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, filtering

I'm trying to do an initial filtering on my datatable, where the process is to filter and show data which the login user was created.
Using Jquery datatable I have initialized it like below:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  "oSearch": {"sSearch": $('#mytext').val() }
} );
```

so I tried to implement it to my code :

```
<!-- JS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/datatable.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add the following if you want to use the jQuery wrapper (you still need datatable.min.js): -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/datatable.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var tableFirst = $('#filetbl').datatable({
    pageSize: 1000,
    sort: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
    filters: [false, false, 'input', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', 'select', false],
    filterText: '検索',
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[data-filter='10']").val(loginuser);
    $('#filetbl').dataTable( {
      "oSearch": {"sSearch": loginuser }
    } );
  });
</script>
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<table id="filetbl" class="table table-hover table-sm">
          <thead style="background-color: #666666;color:#FFF;font-weight: bold; ">
            <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>実験ID</td>
              <td>実験名</td>
              <td>機種</td>
              <td>号機</td>
              <td>フェーズ</td>
              <td>紙種</td>
              <td>温度</td>
              <td>湿度</td>
              <td>登録日</td>
              <td>担当</td>
              <td>バージョン</td>
              <td>操作</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

but on my document ready event, this error always occurred

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

do anybody knows what's the cause of the error?
I think it usually would means I haven't include the JS extension on my code, but as you can see I've already done it.
Could anyone knows what went wrong or please share any tutorial.

Comment: You are initializing `$('#filetbl').datatable()` twice. One in `document ready` and other in `var tableFirst = $('#filetbl').datatable({`  Put everything in `document.ready and avoid multiple initializations of datatable on same id or class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the datatable initialization have mistake

it should be :

> $('#myTable').DataTable();

Comment: @oRoberto , Couldnt find this helpful?